# Avoiding boilerplate session handling code in sqlalchemy functions

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I have a python application which has lots of small database access functions, using sqlalchemy. I'm trying to avoid having lots of boilerplate session handling code around these functions.

I have numerous functions that look something like this:

```
def get_ticket_history(Session, ticket_id):
    s = Session()
    try:
        rows = s.query(TicketHistory)\
                .filter(TicketHistory.ticket_fk==ticket_id)\
                .order_by(TicketHistory.id.desc()).all()
        s.commit()
        return rows
    except:
        s.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        s.close()
```

I am trying to refactor these functions, but not sure I have the best approach yet. The best I currently have is the following:

```
def execute(Session, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    s = Session()
    try:
        ret = fn(s, *args, **kwargs)
        s.commit()
        return ret
    except:
        s.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        s.close()

def get_ticket_history(self, ticket_id):
    def sql_fn(s):
        return s.query(TicketHistory)\
                .filter(TicketHistory.ticket_fk==ticket_id)\
                .order_by(TicketHistory.id.desc()).all()
    return execute(self.sentinel_session, sql_fn)
```

Is there a better or more idiomatic way of doing this? Perhaps using a decorator?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: A `context manager` would be a very good way to go.

Answer (score 55):

The SQLAlchemy docs present a possible way of doing this with context managers.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

Copying the code snippet here for completeness:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

This `session_scope` can be used cleanly without repeating the boiler plate now.

```
class ThingOne(object):
    def go(self, session):
        session.query(FooBar).update({"x": 5})

class ThingTwo(object):
    def go(self, session):
        session.query(Widget).update({"q": 18})

def run_my_program():
    with session_scope() as session:
        ThingOne().go(session)
        ThingTwo().go(session)
```

Answer (score 15):

From Sql alchemy version 1.4:
The Session may be used as a context manager without the use of external helper functions.

Example From documentation

```
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
    session.commit()
```

To begin, commit transaction and close the session, below approach can be applied.

```
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session.begin() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
# commits transaction, closes session
```

Documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker

Comment: Isn't `session.commit()` mandatory, otherwise the transaction is rolled back?

Comment: No, ```.commit()``` and ```.close()``` can also be automatically called. The examples are from docs. Visit the link from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

morphyn's suggestion to use a context manager is good.  You could make such a context manager by applying the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator to a function very much like your first `get_ticket_history`, replacing the code between try and except with a `yield` statement and renaming it, say, `transaction`. [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) has a near-identical example of that name.

Then, use that context manager with the with statement to reimplement `get_ticket_history`.  It looks like SQLAlchemy already provides that function, though, as method `begin`:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#autocommit-mode

Answer (score 0):

#### transaction handling (begin, commit/rolllback) using `with` clause

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), {"col1": 7, "col2": "this is some data"})
```

Old questions, but I still stumbled upon it so here is the relevant link from the docu:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html